# How to get local notification when a user comes within the range of 2 km from his last current location?

Tags: android, notifications, latitude-longitude, android-broadcast

I want to get local notification on my android phone. For example- In starting, user might choose the range like 1km, 2km or 3km as per his own wish and saves this range with his current location(latitude and longitude). After some time user migrates from one location to another means he can go anywhere apart from his current location, his location gets changed. Now in this situation, when he returns towards his last saved location, notification should come on his phone because he is near from his last current location that he saved before when he started to go somewhere. This notification should come when he enters within the specified range by user from his prior saved current location. 
Answer will be appriciated !!!

Comment: you are talking about geofences https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature called **GeoFencing**.

Check the link for sample:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Geofencing

Check google docs and guides for more info:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html